# Codeforces 265A - Div2 - Colorful Stones (Simplified Edition)

Tags: java

I was trying to solve this problem [from codeforces](https://codeforces.com/contest/265/problem/A) and that was my solution,

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ColorfulStonesSE {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = scanner.next();
        String t = scanner.next();
        int counter = 1;
        int index = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i<s.length(); i++)
        {
            for(int j = index; j<t.length(); j++)
            {
                if (s.charAt(i) == t.charAt(j)){
                    counter ++;
                    index = j+1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(counter);
    }
}
```

But it could not pass the 3th test, it gives me 16 instead of 15, can you please tell me where is the error?!

Comment: It seems wrong to have a loop over the `s` string because only the instructions (the `t` string) determine how Liss moves.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is wrong because it loops over all the `s` string (stones) where it should only be looping over the `t` string (instructions).

For example take the following input:

```
RGG
GGB
```

Since the instructions contain no "R" Liss can never leave the first stone - the correct answer is 1. But your solution prints 3 because it loops over the `s` string and finds the two matching "G" instructions.